# Opt-in rate of email sign up form

Tags: website-design, gui-design, user-behavior, email, subscription

Recently I have added a banner on the right panel of our articles page, which includes an email text box for the user to input their email address, submit and subscribe. A link will be emailed to the user to download the ebook. However there are only as little as 9 subscribers in one month.

**Questions**
Is this consider bad response?

How about having banners in between the articles content? Many sites are doing this.

What is the best way to consider what type of banners and placement are more effective?

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to tell if these are good results without knowing your traffic numbers.

In regards to increasing subscriptions: Test it. Try running different setups for banner placement, copy, and design and check what performs best. You may not be getting the numbers you think you should be getting because the banner is placed badly, it might look too much like an advertisement, or the copywriting might be uninteresting or unmotivating. Experiment and test what improves your results.

Remember: when it comes to subscribing to an e-mailservice, your customer needs to know what's in it for him. You mention you give an e-book as a thank-you. Are you marketing it properly? You can write your copy in a way that if your user subscribes, they'll be better at something (this is often what marketing firms do 'Get better conversion using our 10 tips'). What is in your e-book that is really interesting for your visitors?

Comment: Hi Wendy, thanks for your suggestions. I've just check that the ebook subscribe "banner"  subscriber is 9 out of 81 people who subscribed in the last 30 days.

Answer (score 2):

### You are talking about an email sign up form, not a banner.

Also, click through rate (CTR) is relevant for banner ads because it measures what percentage of users open your email. For sign up forms it is more practical to measure the opt-in or subscription rate. That is the percentage of users are successfully subscribing to your email newsletter. So, 3% opt-in rate means that on average 3 users out of 100 subscribe for your emails.

### The average email opt-in rate is 1.95%

That's [according to Sumo](https://sumo.com/stories/email-signup-benchmarks), an email marketing tool which claim to have analyzed 520,000 sites in year 2017. However this stat is an average of different email subscription forms, most of them overlays. So 1% opt-in rate is not very good while 5% or more is great!

### Using overlays should give you higher opt-in rate.

There are studies which tested overlay email sign up forms vs sidebar ones. Basically, the overlay's get much higher conversion rate. One [study found 97% more opt in rate](https://vtldesign.com/web-strategy/conversion-rate-optimization/improve-email-list-subscription-rate/) versus sidebar subscription form. Other one [found 1375% higher opt-in rate](https://blog.aweber.com/email-marketing/easy-secret-more-subscribers.htm).
[image]

Comment: Thanks Kristiyan, I think if I based on my last 30 days subscribers of 9 out of 81, it is consider great since it's more than 5 %.

Comment: @aly92748 That's 11.1% opt-in rate which according to the upper mentioned articles is very very good. Try placing the email subscription form on a lightbox popup for a month and come back to tell us what happened. Ok?

Comment: Currently we're still using the sidebar, I'll try to test it using lightbox next round and come back with the results.

Comment: Actually I'm also curious regarding the click-through rate of side banners vs banners placed in between article content. Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

We can't tell if thats "bad response" if we don't know how many people visited your site and/or saw the banner.

If you had 9 visitors then 9 subscriptions is great, if you had 9000 visitors then your definitely doing something wrong.

Since you did not provide any screenshot i can just assume that your banner looked like advertisement and thats why the visitors did not even look at it.

**Its called banner blindness**

> Banner blindness is a web browsing phenomenon that results in visitors consciously or unconsciously overlooking or skip banner-like assets. When browsing users are often in search mode and may ignore anything irrelevant to their task. Further, usability expert Jakob Nielsen found evidence that people tune out noise to avoid information overload. Visitors also use cognitive schema to focus attention on promising areas where they expect to find the information they are looking for.

Place your subscription box on a different place where its more prominent, make it look different then ads.

Comment: It is too bad that advertising and marketing made it on to the Internet. Same with TV, radio, print media... Radio was originally conceived as a way to "bring culture into every living room." Yeah, right.